# Who can help me out with this c++ project

Tags: android, iphone

You are making a program for a bus service.
A bus can transport 50 passengers at once.
Given the number of passengers waiting in the bus station as input which is 126, you need to calculate and output how many empty seats the last bus will have.

Comment: 50-126%50 ?........

Answer (score 0):

Capacity of the bus = 50 passengers,
number of passengers waiting = 126, therefore the number of empty seats on the bus = 50 - (126%50)

```
int capacity = 50;
int passengers = 126;
int emptySeats = 50 - (126 % 50);
```